# PLSQL oracle select after declare ORA-06550 PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using PL/SQL Developer client.
Oracle throws me ORA-065550 PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "SELECT".
Well, can not find what's wrong here.

```
DECLARE someId NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select id into someId from someTable where someColumn = 'someUniqueValue';
    select * from someTable; --here
END;
select * from someTable; --or here
```

Neither second select, neither third works. When I dmbs_output someId into console it works well, this assigning to declared variable. But why I can not just select after 'into'? I want to declare one time value, and then make
      `select * from someTable where id = someId`
or to be precised want to make like thousand inserts and I want to cache that first select.

```
DECLARE someId NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select id into someId from someTable where someColumn = 'someValue';
END;
/
select * from otherTable where otherTableId = someId;
```

Here I lost someId scope I guess.

Comment: you cannot use an original select in a pl/sql unit

Comment: what do you want to achive with that? "select * from someTable; --here"

Comment: @Thomas I want to store value in variable for next 10 thousands inserts. Just not to select it again 10 thousand times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you doing a lot of mistakes while doing this code.

1.You cant just `'SELECT *'` in the anonymous block. You need to have cursor to do it.

2.Your variable scope is till the anonymous block. Now you are trying to access the variable outside the block --> NAAH not possible.

So I have tried to resolve your issue by below snippet hope it helps.

```
DECLARE
  someId NUMBER;
  p_lst sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO someId FROM someTable WHERE someColumn = 'someUniqueValue';
  OPEN p_lst FOR
  'SELECT * FROM someTable 
   where otherTableId = '||someId; 
END;
```

Comment: Well, great, it worked. Thanks. I realised that I was doing it wrong. And I guess, that's not the thing I want to accomplish :( Neither I know the solution atm. Cause like in T-SQL I use Declare /@id int     set /@id = (select...) I want to use it just like that in oracle db. And I can not find a way to do it :( But thanks! ;)

Comment: Well if you get to know what solution is expected you can post a new question on it. We will be happy to answer that :P

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're coding a sql script, you can

1) declare your variable
2) populate it in an anonymous pl/sql block
3) use it elsewhere

```
    --1 
   variable my_num number
    --2
    begin
      select 1 into :my_num from dual;
    end;
    /
    --3
    select :my_num from dual;
```

Comment: Nah, that's not the issue here. keyword variable gives me ORA-00900. And I thought maybe it's the '/' slash issue. But after that, me DECLARE someId number is lost. Am I closing scope by using slash? Updating main thread

Comment: This is client-specific functionality. SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer allow it, and I believe PL/SQL Developer does in some modes. The OP's client doesn't seem to.

Comment: You're right Alex, but as far as I know, most clients allow this, with exception of PL/SQL developer. TOAD also supports this functionality.

Comment: Ah, shame I'm using this PL/SQL developer ;P thanks for that info.

Answer (score 1):

That you can achieve through using SQL*Plus

```
SQL> variable id number
SQL> begin
       select 1000 into :id from dual;
     end;
     /

SQL> print id

        ID
----------
      1000

SQL> SELECT * FROM tbl_a WHERE id = :id
```

---

In Oracle doesn't let you implicitly return the result of a query. The result always has to be explicitly returned in some fashion. The simplest way is to use DBMS_OUTPUT (roughly equivalent to print) to output the variable:

```
DECLARE
   myname varchar2(20);
BEGIN
     myname := 'Tom';

     dbms_output.print_line(myname);
END;
```

This isn't terribly helpful if you're trying to return a result set, however. In that case, you'll either want to return a collection or a refcursor. However, using either of those solutions would require wrapping your code in a function or procedure and running the function/procedure from something that's capable of consuming the results. A function that worked in this way might look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function (myname in varchar2)
     my_refcursor out sys_refcursor
BEGIN
     open my_refcursor for
     SELECT *
     FROM   Customers
     WHERE  Name = myname;

     return my_refcursor;
END my_function;
```